# Characters on webpage changing on refresh

Tags: asp.net, iis, character-encoding

The web server is sending back two different responses.

One response is correct and is probably getting the correct character codes.

The other response does not have the correct character codes.

The **incorrect** source code looks like this:
Name愀 Test

The **correct** source code looks like this:
Name's Test.

If I refresh 10 times, most of the time the apostrophe is there.  One or two times the "Chinese" character is there.  I know that the character codes is the same and that the character set is probably getting goofed up.  Being able to refresh and get either or has stumped me.

I understand that there are different character sets.

***btw***: For those that want a great character set historical reference. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/all-about-unicode-utf8-character-sets/

ASP generated pages.
The server is IIS.
The request setting is utf-8. 
The response encoding is utf-8. 
The File encoding is Windows-1252.
Culture: Invariant
UI Culture: Invariant 
The ASP.NET support version is 4.5.2

The back end is MS Access Database.  *(Client's choice not mine).*

I can reliably reproduce the problem.

How do I fix it?

Is it a server setting?

Other threads says to disable compression and check the header.  What's the correct advice.

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Any tips on future debugging is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ASP file was setting the language:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript LCID=1033 CODEPAGE = 1252%>
```

This character encoding is a superset of ISO 8859-1.  It is a single-byte character encoding of the Latin alphabet, used by default in the legacy components of Microsoft.

There was an Apache reverse proxy to pass the traffic to a Windows server

```
<Location "/SomeFolder/">
      ProxyPass "http://someurl.com/SomeFolder/"
      ProxyPassReverse "http://someurl.com/SomeFolder/"
      RequestHeader    unset  Accept-Encoding
      AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1
</Location>
```

Enabling the explicit reverse proxy option allowed the character encoding to pass though properly.